# Find uncommon elements using hashing

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, c++14, hashset

I think this is a fairly common question but I didn't find any answer for this using hashing in C++.

I have two arrays, both of the same lengths, which contain some elements, for example:

```
A={5,3,5,4,2}
B={3,4,1,2,1}
```

Here, the uncommon elements are: {5,5,1,1}

I have tried this approach- iterating a while loop on both the arrays **after sorting**:

```
while(i<n && j<n) {
    if(a[i]<b[j])
            uncommon[k++]=a[i++];
    else if (a[i] > b[j])
            uncommon[k++]=b[j++];
    else {    
            i++;
            j++;
    }
}
while(i<n && a[i]!=b[j-1])
    uncommon[k++]=a[i++];
while(j < n && b[j]!=a[i-1])
    uncommon[k++]=b[j++];
```

and I am getting the correct answer with this. However, I want a better approach in terms of time complexity since sorting both arrays every time might be computationally expensive.

I tried to do hashing but couldn't figure it out entirely.

To insert elements from arr1[]:

```
set<int> uncommon; 
    for (int i=0;i<n1;i++) 
        uncommon.insert(arr1[i]);
```

To compare arr2[] elements:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) 
        if (uncommon.find(arr2[i]) != uncommon.end())
```

Now, what I am unable to do is to send only those elements to the uncommon array[] which are uncommon to both of them.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you do something like this: instead of having set type int make it pair<int, bool> (the bool indicates whether it is common or not)?

Comment: Perhaps you can use one of the methods on std::set? For example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/

Comment: Hashing could also fail if numbers are pretty large like `10^9` because you cant make an array of that size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, std::set does not have anything to do with hashing. Sets and maps are ordered containers. Implementations may differ, but most likely it is a binary search tree. Whatever you do, you wont get faster that n*logn with them - the same complexity as sorting.
If you're fine with n*logn and sorting, I'd strongly advice just using set_symmetric_difference algorithm https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference , it requires two sorted containers.

But if you insist on an implementation relying on hashing, you should use std::unordered_set or std::unordered_map. This way you can be faster than n*logn. You can get your answer in n*m time, where n = a.size() and m = b.size(). You should create two unordered_set`s: hashed_a, hashed_b and in two loops check what elements from hashed_a are not in hashed_b, and what elements in hashed_b are not in hashed_a. Here a pseudocode:

```
create hashed_a and hashed_b
create set_result // for the result
for (a_v : hashed_a) 
  if (a_v not in hashed_b)
    set_result.insert(a_v)
for (b_v : hashed_b) 
  if (b_v not in hashed_a)
    set_result.insert(b_v)
return set_result // it holds the symmetric diference, which you need
```

**UPDATE:** as noted in the comments, my answer doesn't count for duplicates. The easiest way to modify it for duplicates would be to use unordered_map<int, int> with the keys for elements in the set and values for number of encounters.

Comment: This wouldn't solve for duplicates though, would it? For example, if there are two 5s in the first set and one 5 in the second set, it wouldn't add a 5 to set_result, although it should.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find a way to distinguish between the same values contained in the same array (for ex. 5 and 5 in the first array, and 1 and 1 in the second array). This is the key to reducing the overall complexity, otherwise you can't do better than `O(nlogn)`. A good possible algorithm for this task is to create a wrapper object to hold your actual values, and put in your arrays pointers to those wrapper objects with actual data, so your pointer addresses will serve as a unique identifier for objects. This wrapping will cost you just `O(n1+n2)` operations, but also an additional `O(n1+n2)` space.

Now your problem is that you have in both arrays only elements unique to each of those arrays, and you want to find the uncommon elements. This means the `(Union of both array elements) - (Intersection of both array elements)`. Therefore, all you need to do is to push all the elements of the first array into a hash-map (complexity `O(n1)`), and then start pushing all the elements of the second array into the same hash-map (complexity `O(n2)`), by detecting the collisions (equality of an element from first array with an element from the second array). This comparison step will require `O(n2)` comparisons in the worst case. So for the maximum performance optimization you could have checked the size of the arrays before starting pushing the elements into the hash-map, and swap the arrays so that the first push will take place with the longest array. Your overall algorithm complexity would be `O(n1+n2)` pushes (hashings) and `O(n2)` comparisons.

The implementation is the most boring stuff, so I let it to you ;)

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I am rather new to maps. How do you detect collisions and how do you delete the elements if there are collisions?

Comment: @KashishArora, the collision is when the hashes of 2 different objects results to the same hash. I don't understand exactly what you mean by deleting the elements, I didn't mention any delete operation in my algorithm description.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without sorting (and without hashing but you seem to care more about complexity then the hashing itself) is to notice the following : an uncommon element e is an element that is in exactly one multiset.

This means that the multiset of all uncommon elements is the union between 2 multisets:

1. S1 = The element in A that are not in B
2. S2 = The element in B that are not in A

Using the std::set_difference, you get:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    std::multiset<int> ms1{5,3,5,4,2};


    std::multiset<int> ms2{3,4,1,2,1};

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::set_difference( ms1.begin(), ms1.end(), ms2.begin(), ms2.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
    std::set_difference( ms2.begin(), ms2.end(), ms1.begin(), ms1.end(), std::back_inserter(v));

    for(int e : v)
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5 5 1 1
```

The complexity of this code is 4.(N1+N2 -1) where N1 and N2 are the size of the multisets.

Links:

set_difference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference

compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/o3KGbf

Answer (score 1):

The Question can Be solved in `O(nlogn)` time-complexity.

**ALGORITHM**

- `Sort both array with merge sort in O(nlogn) complexity. You can also use sort-function.  For example sort(array1.begin(),array1.end())`.
- `Now use two pointer method to remove all common elements on both arrays`.
- **Program of above Method**

```
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    while (i < array1.size() && j < array2.size()) { 
  
        // If not common, print smaller 
        if (array1[i] < array2[j]) { 
            cout << array1[i] << " "; 
            i++; 
        } 
        else if (array2[j] < array1[i]) { 
            cout << array2[j] << " ";  
            j++; 
        } 

        // Skip common element 
        else { 
            i++; 
            j++; 
        } 
    }
```

- Complexity of above program is `O(array1.size() + array2.size())`. In worst case say `O(2n)`
- The above program gives the uncommon elements as output. If you want to store them , just create a vector and push them into vector.
- Original Problem [LINK](https://www.codechef.com/JULY20B/problems/CHFNSWPS)

Comment: I have mentioned the two-pointer method in the question itself and wanted a slightly better approach. Thank you for the answer though!